# Best way to create smart autocompletion for SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, autocomplete, ide, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to create an online SQL editor with smart autocompletion. What the best way to do it?

If i have empty input field (**|** - *current carriage position*), editor must suggest **SELECT**, **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE**.

If i had types this: **SELECT * FROM |**, editor must suggest list of available tables. But if i return to **SELECT *, | FROM people**, editor must suggest list of fields of **people** table.

If i had types this: **SELECT p.name, a.| FROM people p LEFT JOIN address a ON p.address_id = a.id**, editor must suggest list of fields of **address** table.

Also how to support subqueries?

I think to determine what to suggest editor must know where are carriage now? At which SQL token.

Is AST tree applicable here? What to do with invalid SQL statements?

Comment: You would implement the grammar for SQL and use that.  Here is a place to start:  http://www.savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html.

Comment: Can you describe more details?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a suffix tree with the SQL grammar

As user types the words , traverse through the suffix tree and give all children from the matching node as auto completion words

This is similar to how Google gives suggestions when entering search field